# Does the homogeneity of space imply that the expansion of the universe is uniform?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, symmetry, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

Obviously, homogeneity implies that the density is the same everywhere at any time. However, does this imply that the expansion is uniform? By uniformity, I mean that if I pick three galaxies to form a triangle, then the ratio of the side lengths will never change over time.

EDIT: I have forgotten to add this: **if both homogeneity and isotropy are assumed, can we prove that the expansion is uniform?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, homogeneity does not implies that the expansion is uniform. Homogeneous expansion could be anisotropic which would lead to different changes in length depending on orientation.

A simple example to demonstrate this is the [Kasner metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasner_metric) which is homogeneous but anisotropic. For a $(3+1)$ spacetime this metric could be written in the following form:
$$
 ds^2 = - dt^2 +t^{2p_1} dx^2 +t^{2p_2} dy^2 +t^{2p_3} dz^2.
$$

Now let us assume that we have  three galaxies at a moment $t=1$ first at origin $(0,0,0)$, second at a point with spatial coordinates $(a,0,0)$, third at a point $(0,b,0)$.

At the moment $t=\tau$ these galaxies would have the following spatial coordinates: first $(0,0,0)$, second $(\tau^{2p_1} a,0,0)$, third $(0,\tau^{2p_2} b ,0)$.

We see that if $p_1\ne p_2$ then the ratio of the distances $d_{1-2}/d_{1-3}$ would be different at different times.

Comment: Thank you a lot! What about having BOTH homogeneity AND isotropy assumed? Can we deduce uniform expansion in this case?

Comment: @MaJoad: You might want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @BenCrowell OK. Here is the new thread: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/508640/does-the-homogeneity-and-isotropy-of-space-imply-that-the-expansion-of-the-unive